# JQuery Dialog text area disappears on clicking on any other input

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing .NET MVC3 application in which I am using jquery dialog to display some text msg and text area together in pop up with OK Cancel button which is in a div "divForSentToCaseCommentLable". I am calling this dialog on button click "sentToCase".

chtml

```
<div id="divForSentToCaseComment">
                    <div id="divForSentToCaseCommentLable" style="display: none">
                        <b>
                            @Html.Raw("You are about to send the Alert to the Case Management queue and will be unable to make any further edits.")
                            <br />
                             @Html.Raw("Would you like to continue?")
                        </b>
                        <br />
                        @Html.Raw("Reason for status change:")
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange" style="display: none">
                        @Html.TextArea("StatusDueDateChangeComment", new { @id = "StatusDueDateChangeComment", @name = "StatusDueDateChangeComment", String.Empty, @class = "text-box multi-line", @maxlength = "8000", @onkeypress = "return ImposeMaxLength(this,8000)", @onpaste = "return MaxLengthPaste(this,8000)" })
                        <div id="StatusCommentValidateMessage" style="display: none" />
                    </div>

                </div>
```

JQuery

```
$("#sentToCase").click(function () {

    if (isChanged && !isSubmit) {
        var conf = confirm("The changes you made have not been saved. \nWould you like to continue?");
        if (!conf) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    $("#StatusDueDateChangeComment").val('');
    $("#StatusCommentValidateMessage").hide();
    $("#divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange").show();
    $("#divForSentToCaseCommentLable").show();

    $('#divForSentToCaseComment').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        width: 415,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        fontsize: 10,
        title: 'Reason for send to case',
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                //                    var sendToCaseAnswer = confirm("You are about to send the Alert to Cases and will be unable to make any further edits.  Would you like to continue?");
                //                    if (sendToCaseAnswer) {
                var reasonForClear = $("#StatusDueDateChangeComment").val();
                var incidentId = $("#IncidentID").val();
                if (validateSatusComment(reasonForClear, "SentToCase")) {
                    $.blockUI({ message: '<h2><img src="../../Content/images/spinner.gif" />Loading ...</h2>' });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { incidentId: incidentId, reasonForClear: reasonForClear },
                        //url: '/Bamplus/AlertAndCaseManager/Alert/SendToCaseStatus',
                        url: sendToCaseStatusJsonUrl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.redirectTo != null) {
                                window.location = data.redirectTo;
                                $.unblockUI({ fadeOut: 200 });
                            } else {
                                $('#Messages').show(400);
                                $("#Messages").html(data.Html);
                                $.unblockUI({ fadeOut: 200 });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {

                            $.unblockUI({ fadeOut: 200 });

                        }
                    });
                    //                    }
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
        }, open: function () {
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Cancel")').removeClass().addClass("Button");
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Ok")').removeClass().addClass("Button");
        }

    });
    $("#divForSentToCaseComment").dialog("open");
    return false;


});
```

There is another button "watching" which is calling "divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange" div in dialog box to display only text area with Ok Cancel button

JQuery:

```
$("#watching").click(function () {
    if (isChanged && !isSubmit) {
        var conf = confirm("The changes you made have not been saved. \nWould you like to continue?");
        if (!conf) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
    $('#divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 350,
        height: 220,
        modal: true,
        fontsize: 10,
        title: 'Reason for status change',
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                var reasonForClear = $("#StatusDueDateChangeComment").val();
                var incidentId = $("#IncidentID").val();
                if (validateSatusComment(reasonForClear, "Watching")) {
                    $.blockUI({ message: '<h2><img src="../../Content/images/spinner.gif" />Loading ...</h2>' });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        data: { incidentId: incidentId, reasonForClear: reasonForClear },
                        //url: '/Bamplus/AlertAndCaseManager/Alert/WatchingStatus',
                        url: watchingStatusJsonUrl,
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.redirectTo != null) {
                                window.location = result.redirectTo;
                                $.unblockUI({ fadeOut: 200 });
                            } else {
                                $('#Messages').show(400);
                                $("#Messages").html(result.Html);
                                $.unblockUI({ fadeOut: 200 });
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {

                            $.unblockUI({ fadeOut: 200 });

                        }
                    });
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Cancel")').removeClass().addClass("Button");
            $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:contains("Ok")').removeClass().addClass("Button");
        }
    });
    $("#StatusDueDateChangeComment").val('');
    $("#StatusCommentValidateMessage").hide();
    $("#divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Problem-

scenario 1:

- on page load I click on "watching" button to display "watching pop-up" with only
  text area and "OK Cancel button", which is perfect.
- Then I press "Cancel button" from "watching pop-up" which will hide "watching pop-up"
- Now I go for "sentToCase" button from main page to display "sentToCase pop-up" with text message and text area.
- I found that text area is not rendering in "sentToCase pop-up", I can only see text message in "sentToCase pop-up".

scenario 2:

- On first page load if I directly click on "sentToCase" button then, "sentToCase pop-up" correctly renders text message and text area with "OK cancel button" which is correct.

Comment: I got the solution form this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849310/jquery-ui-dialog-box-removes-div-after-closing

Comment: divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange is very long. try to keep it short as everything matters when the page renders. long names will increase the page size at client side.

Comment: yes sure, I will try to keep the small names. thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem by referring this post

[jquery ui dialog box removes <div> after closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849310/jquery-ui-dialog-box-removes-div-after-closing)

The problem here is that you have your dialogs nested. The way jQuery dialog works is that it assumes all dialogs must be exclusive. Do not nest your dialogs, and you should be ok.

after separating div's existing code works fine. I done it like this

```
<div id="divForSentToCaseComment">
                    <div id="divForSentToCaseCommentLable" style="display: none">
                        <b>
                            @Html.Raw("You are about to send the Alert to the Case Management queue and will be unable to make any further edits.")
                            <br />
                            @Html.Raw("Would you like to continue?")
                        </b>
                        <br />
                        @Html.Raw("Reason for status change:")
                        <br />
                    </div>
                    <div id="divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChangeSendToCase" style="display: none">
                        @Html.TextArea("StatusDueDateChangeComment", new { @id = "StatusDueDateChangeCommentSendTocase", @name = "StatusDueDateChangeComment", String.Empty, @class = "text-box multi-line", @maxlength = "8000", @onkeypress = "return ImposeMaxLength(this,8000)", @onpaste = "return MaxLengthPaste(this,8000)" })
                         <div id="StatusCommentValidateMessageSendToCase" style="display: none" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divShowCommentForStatusNDuedateChange" style="display: none">
                        @Html.TextArea("StatusDueDateChangeComment", new { @id = "StatusDueDateChangeComment", @name = "StatusDueDateChangeComment", String.Empty, @class = "text-box multi-line", @maxlength = "8000", @onkeypress = "return ImposeMaxLength(this,8000)", @onpaste = "return MaxLengthPaste(this,8000)" })
                         <div id="StatusCommentValidateMessage" style="display: none" />
                    </div>
```

but because of separate divs I need to do some extra efforts on validation an all.
Thank you